# Partial View is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm learning to use Partial Views in MVC. It's working if I just have some simple text in the Partial View, but when I'm trying to use data from the Model, I get some problem! I guess I'm missing some point and need some guidance.

I'm trying to use a Partial View inside HomeController index file.

The code inside the index file:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" id="listOfNames">
    @Html.Partial("ListPersonLayoutPartialView")
</div>
</div>
```

And the Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestAjaxAutoSuggest.Models.Person>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<div class="personBlock">@item.Name</div>
}
<p>Test</p>
```

And finally the action method in the Home controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListPersonLayout()
    {
        return PartialView("ListPersonLayoutPartialView", db.People.ToList());
    }
```

I guess something is missing, like the how the data from the Controller connects to the Partial View!?

Comment: Where you get error, at Index or ListPersonLayout action? At Index View you not pass model to @Html.Partial.

Comment: The partial view implementation looks correct. Try trouble-shooting to see if your controller is actually passing data by skipping the partial implementation and put that code directly into the index page - be sure to reference @model. Let me know if that works...

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It's working now thanks to the answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Html.Action` here not `Html.Partial`,if you want to render partial view  `Html.Partial` then you have to pass `Model` as well from Main view, which are not passing, so Model is `null` and additionally `Html.Partial` does not call action, for calling action you have use `Html.Action` which will in return renders partial view:

```
@Html.Action("ListPersonLayout")
```

you need to understand difference of these two, for that you can see [this post](http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.nl/2011/11/htmlpartial-vs-htmlaction-mvc-razor.html)

Comment: If you will use ListPersonLayout action only at context of rendering Views, there is sense to add `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to this action.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ListPersonLayout` and not `ListPersonLayoutPartialView` as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="listOfNames">
        @Html.Partial("ListPersonLayout")
    </div>
</div>
```